# Why a finite dimensional algebra always has a smallest submodule having semisimple quotient

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, modules

$A$ is a finite-dimensional algebra (possible without unit, the corresponding field is $\mathbb{F}$), I want to prove that A has a smallest submodule having semisimple quotient. What I have got is that if $M$ and $N$ are submodules of $A$ (as an $A$-module) such that $A/M$ and $A/N$ are semisimple $A$-modules, then $A/M\cap N$ is a semisimple $A$-module.

So to prove the original proposition, all I need to do is to prove that there are at most finite submodules of $A$ having semisimple quotient. If I prove this, I can finish my job by using the result above and by induction. But I don't know how to prove this.

Any help or hint will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that submodules are also $\mathbb{F}$-vector spaces and as such have a well defined dimension. No matter how many submodules there are, there are only finitely many possibilities for their dimension.

Let $k$ be the smallest dimension such that a submodule $M$ with $A/M$ semi-simple exists.

If there are somehow $M_1, M_2$ (and perhaps finitely or infinitely many others) of dimension $k$ and with semi-simple quotient, we can use your result to get a contradiction. So we conclude that $M$ is the only dimension $k$ submodule with semi-simple quotient.

This solves your problem for a not-so-elegant definition of smallest. In order to get to the better definition ($M$ is contained in every $N$ such that $A/N$ is semi-simple) we can - again! - apply your result!

Comment: Thanks first! But why  submodules of $A$ are also $\mathbb{F}$-vector spaces? In fact I've tried to prove this but got nothing.

Comment: Suppose that $M$ is a submodule of $A$, and $m\in M$， how can I prove that $\alpha m\in M$ for any $\alpha\in \mathbb{F}$ if $A$ does not have a unit?

Comment: Right, that is a good point, I didn't think that through. Well for one thing: the submodule $AM$ of $M$ *is* a vectorspace because there every element is of the form $am$ for some $a \in A, m \in M$ and then every $\alpha(am) = (\alpha a)m$ is also in $AM$. But yeah, it seems now that $M$ could be the union of $AM$ and some random other stuff even if this 'feels' wrong. Hmmm. Perhaps we should cook up an extra argument that if $A/M$ is semi-simple, then so is $A/AM$? But that doesn't sound really plausible either. Ok, I have to think more about it.

Comment: I noted that my textbook assumes that all $A$-module are $\mathbb{F}$-vector spaces, so as all submodules of $A$ are $A$-modules, they are also subspaces of $A$. Sorry that I forgot this assumption. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome! Still it would be nice to think about your more general definition of $A$-module as a separate project. The first thing we need I guess is a 'natural' example of such a module that is not an $\mathbb{F}$-vector space

Comment: I agree with you. Actually I found it strange when the textbook assumes that all the $A$-modules are $\mathbb{F}$-vector spaces.

Comment: Maybe historically people only studied modules over unital algebras, where it is inevitable? And by the time people started studying modules over algebras without unit we all had just become so used to modules over algebras being vector spaces that we didn't think more about it? I'm just speculating here...